# How do I access this external GFCI outlet? The cover doesn't seem easily removable

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

An electrician installed this outdoor outlet on my deck a couple of years ago.

When we went to use it, we couldn't figure out how to expose the outlet to plug anything in.  This stubborn cover seems to block everything except the GFCI buttons.

I tried pulling on various parts of the plastic without any success.

Any information is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you press the little tab up/down that is near the top directly above the word "closed" and see if that make the cover movable ?

Comment: Are there any brand or model marking on that box? Looks like on the left, there is some sort of contraption that powers something through a part of the box that's plugged into the receptacle.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a screw to be removed:

[image]

Possibly two screws where the other one is hidden in the picture.

Comment: Wow. Good eye!!